# Keycloak email template with frontend url

Tags: keycloak

Is it possible to get the Frontend url defined on the Realm Settings and pass it to the kcSanitize method to be used in the keycloak email template, for example:

password-reset.ftl:

```
${kcSanitize(msg("passwordResetBodyHtml", frontEndUrl, link, linkExpiration, realmName, linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration), user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getEmail()))?no_esc}
```

message.properties:

```
passwordResetBodyHtml: Frontend Url {0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the source code you can only access the realmName. I helped myself in a similar situation by defining a variable in the theme.properties for example

```
myLoginURL=${env.MY_LOGIN_URL}
```

and in your template you can access this as

```
<a class="zocial" href="${properties.myLoginURL}">
```

Comment: That's could be good a alternative depending on the arch/deployment schemes, thanks.